# How do I execute an arbitrary script in the context of my Django project?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-command-extensions

Sometimes I want to execute a file in the context of my Django project, just as if I were using the shell, but with the convenience of using a text editor.  This is mainly to try something out, or quickly prototype some functionality before putting it into a view, test, recurring task, or management command.

I know I can stick these lines at the top of my .py file and it'll run in the Django context:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/location/of/projet')
from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

I thought it'd be easier to make a management command that takes on argument, a python module to run, and executes it in the Django environment.   Here's the 'runmodule' command I wrote:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "Runs an arbitrary module, in the Django environment, for quick prototyping of code that's too big for the shell."

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        if not args:
            return
        module_name = args[0]

        try:
            __import__(module_name)
        except ImportError:
            print("Unable to import module %s.  Check that is within Django's PYTHONPATH" % (module_name))
```

This looks like it works -- I can stick some code in a module, and pass it as an argument to this command, and it'll get executed, e.g.

```
python manage.py runmodule myapp.trysomethingout
```

which will execute myapp/trysomethingout.py.  Is this the best way to do this?

Answer (score 9):

The best way to execute a script with the correct django context is to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable to your settings module (and appropriate `PYTHONPATH` if needed).  In windows this usually means executing:

```
set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=setting
```

and in bash :

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=setting
```

You can now import your models etc.

see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings .

Note that in order to import the `settings` module, one should use `from django.conf import settings`.  This takes into account the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` instead of automatically using settings.py .

Comment: you can put it directly on your python script on your if __name__ == "__main__": with this line: os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings")

Answer (score 2):

Here's the simplest solution:

```py
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

import django
django.setup()
```

Be sure to include this **at the top** of your python file, before importing any of your models.

Alternatively, you could use the solution pointed out by @beyondfloatingpoint:

```py
import os, sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
sys.path.append("mysite")
os.chdir("mysite")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is provided in [this](https://www.stavros.io/posts/standalone-django-scripts-definitive-guide/) article.

Hints: Make sure you are using correct path to settings module, in my case, I missed nested dirs named the same way. The best way to avoid my mistake is to use something like [this](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template) template to start with.